# Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous using Eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Does anyone know why the following is resulting in a Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous error?

```
$app_subj_current = \DB::table('tbl_subject')
        ->join('tbl_application', 'tbl_subject.id', '=', 'tbl_application.app_subj_id')
        ->where('tbl_application.id', $application)
        ->lists('tbl_subject.subj_type', 'tbl_subject.id');
```

I've specified the table for which ID I'm referring to so I cannot understand why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured out that the following fixes the problem:

```
$app_subj_current = \DB::table('tbl_subject')
    ->join('tbl_application', 'tbl_subject.id', '=', 'tbl_application.app_subj_id')
    ->where('tbl_application.id', $application)
    ->select('tbl_subject.subj_type as x', 'tbl_subject.id as y')
    ->lists('x', 'y');
```

Answer (score -2):

use `select()` instead of `lists()`. hope it work.

Comment: This results in a htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error

Comment: I've tried it out of curiosity and it still results in the htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given error for me. I have a working fix though (see my answer).